# AB is a chord, find point p on circle such that pa.pb and pa+pb are maximum

Tags: optimization, circles

is a chord of a circle .
(a) Find a point  on the circumference of  such that . is the maximum.
(b) Find a point  on the circumference of  which maximizes +.

My work:
(a)I draw a chord  on the cirlce , and choose any random point  to construct the triangle. Now, let the area of the triangle inscribed in the circle be Δ and the radius of the circle be .
know for PA.PB to be maximum PA=PB hence the triangle is an isosceles triangle

Comment: Do you know trig?

Comment: How do you "know" the maxmum of $PA \cdot PB$ is attained when $PA=PB$?

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676392/abc-3-a-b-c0-prove-that-a2b2c2-ge-3-2a3-2b3-2c/676655#676655) answer in the linked dupe.